# data between <![CDATA[]]> returns empty XML, simplexml

Tags: xml

Im using `simplexml` in order to get data from an Online Newspaper (working link)

```
   https://larepublica.pe/noticiasfeed.xml?outputType=rss
```

**This is how I retrieve**

```
   $xml=simplexml_load_file($feedUrl, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

   $entries=array_merge($entries,$xml->xpath("//item"));
```

**printing:**

```
    $title = trim($entry->title)
    $article.=trim($entry->description)."<br/>";
```

It only returns the title correctly, but `description` returns empty : this is between `<![CDATA[]]>`...

**I try adding the next lines but without success**

```
     //$json = json_encode($xml);
    //$entries= json_encode($entries, true);
```

**What am doing wrong?** (the xlm link above works and is the one Im having issues like this, while Im not having the same problem with another links using this script)

Comment: you use the NO CDATA flag: `$xml=simplexml_load_file($feedUrl, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);` try removing it

Comment: @NikosM. Ive already removed it but still not displaying the `description` data